# Running 32-bit programs on 21.04

Tags: 32-bit, 21.04

I am new to Ubuntu and might have made a big mistake, just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on an old PC and trying to run a 32 bit program on it. Looking it up it appears I have to run the following to make it compatable with a 64 bit operating system.
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt install lib32z1

On running  “dpkg --add-architecture i386”  I get

```
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
```

Looked at the offending file
“foreign-architecture i386”.
On running “apt install lib.32z1”

```
root@g1gxb-ubuntu:/home/g1gxb# apt install lib32z1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm11
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  lib32z1 libc6-i386
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/2,689 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown 
option 'foreign-architecture'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Add to your question the complete contents of the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

Comment: root@g1gxb-ubuntu:/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d# ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  8 14:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug  8 12:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26 Aug  8 10:46 multiarch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  204 Apr 26  2020 pkg-config-hook-config
and the file contains.
post-invoke=if { test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = add-architecture || test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = remove-architect>

Comment: @KeithRay please [edit] that information into your question so that it is properly formated. FWIW I don't think either `lib32z1` or `libc6-i386` are packages from the i386 foreign architecture (if they were, they'd be named something like `libc6:i386`)

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/ubuntu-is-dropping-all-32-bit-support-going-forward → → "Ubuntu has confirmed plans to drop all support for 32-bit (i386) systems going forward, beginning with the upcoming Ubuntu 19.10 release". .... ?Ubuntu 20.04 may still install / run 32bit ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen  A long list of 32-bit libraries are still supported to provide compatibility with Steam, Wine, and other common uses. Ubuntu no longer produces complete 32-bit systems, and has dropped support for a different long list of 32-bit libraries due to a lack of volunteers to test and maintain them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Had to delete two files in the /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d, Multiarch and pkg-config-hook-config and then it all worked

Comment: The pkg-config-hook-config file is useful, you have to reinstall it by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" pkg-config ` .